# What are the disadvantages if you use ThisWorkBook-Object as a intermediary storage for objects?

Tags: excel, vba, mvp

I use the following system to intermediarily store a model-object in the ThisWorkBook-Object in VBA Excel.

**In ThisWorkBook-Object**

```
Private Type TView
    Model As UIModel
    'UserInterface As UIFrm
End Type

Private this As TView

Friend Property Get Model() As UIModel
    Set Model = this.Model
End Property

Friend Property Set Model(ByVal value As UIModel)
    Set this.Model = value
    'Validate
End Property
```

**When called from a module**

```
if ThisWorkBook.Model is nothing then 
  'Do Stuff
End If
```

ThisWorkBook has to be translated into your Excel language (e.g in german DieseArbeitsMappe.Model)

This works and the model can be stored an recalled later, even if the code has run to the end and usually all objects would be destroyed. If there is an error even the model in the ThisWorkBook-objects are destroyed and reinitialized. But now to the question:

**1. Has this method significant disadvantages?**

**2. Is there a safer way of intermediary storing objects in Excel-VBA?**